# Is it possible to create a virtual bluetooth device on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, thermal-printer, point-of-sale

Well, I have the following problem: I need to print some things using a build-in thermal printer on an mPOS terminal running Android 7.1.1, however the applications I need to print can only detect Bluetooth printers, so how could I be creating a virtual bluetooth device that can be paired with the device? I know it's possible to do this, since Sunmi terminals, like my Sunmi P2, do this, it has a paired virtual bluetooth device called "InnerPrint" that converts the received content and sends it to the printer via API.